# What does await fn(browser) do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm looking into ways of speeding up puppeteer with parallelization. I've come across https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-speed-up-puppeteer-scraping-with-parallelization/ which looks interesting. This has:

```
const withBrowser = async (fn) => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({/* ... */});
try {
    return await fn(browser);
} finally {
    await browser.close();
}
}
```

I don't understand fn(browser) in line 4. Can someone explain this?

Comment: this should allow you to pass callback function into `withBrowser` to execute code in that context. It'd be much more useful with typescript...

Answer (score 1):

That site there shows an example call of `withBrowser` as:

```
await withBrowser(async (browser) => {
    for (const url of urls) {
        const result = await withPage(browser)(async (page) => {
            await page.goto(url);

            // run test code
            return ...;
        });

        results.push(result);
    }
});
```

In short, it's just a function that takes a Puppeteer browser as an argument and does some asynchronous stuff, returning a Promise. The page is arguing that by wrapping the *meat* of the code in a `withBrowser` function, it makes it easy to be sure that the browser is disposed of properly after everything is finished.